# how to display search terms while user is typing in search field

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am creating a search tool for students where they can look up courses based on what they enter in search field.

For eg. Lets say I have the following values stored in "Courses" table:

1. Math - Calculus I
2. Math - Calculus II
3. Math - Probability
4. Math - Differential Equations
5. Math - Stochastic
6. Science - Physics
7. Science - Biology
8. Science - Chemistry

So, as soon as any student starts entering something in search field I want to display a list of possible search items they may be looking for (something like Google). So, if they enter "Mat" I want to display a list of all text that contains "Mat" right below the search field - again, similar to how google displays a list underneath the search field.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the jquery autocomplete plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AJAX control toolkit released by Microsoft includes a control called the AutoCompleteExtender and from personal use, it's exactly what you're looking for, it's fast and it doesn't require a lot of setup.

Here's the basic information page for the toolkit: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/get-started-with-the-ajax-control-toolkit-cs

And here's the how-to specifically for the AutoCompleteExtender:
http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/ajax-tutorials/using-autocomplete-in-the-ajax-toolkit/

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your looking for code you can put on the client side. Check out [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)